# All the sender profile is not showing in journey builder message configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud

The number of sender profile under admin section is more when compare to list of sender profile shown in the journey builder message configuration.
Kindly help me out in finding a solution for it.

Comment: Only sender profiles with a verified email address will show up in JB